# altclass is not working in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to make zebra effect in jqgrid.For this purpose i use `altclass` property in jqgrid.Following is my code:

```
altRow:true,
altclass:'myAltRowClass'
```

and my css is

```
.myAltRowClass
 {
     background-color: Fuchsia;
     background-image:none;
     }
```

every thing is fine but is not working for me.
kindly solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **altRows** (plural):

altRows: true

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem, but all works perfectly in my tests. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AltRows.htm).

Comment: finally done thanks @OLEG but my loading image is hide due to color on row.